# Document labled Utf-16 but has Utf-8 content XML

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

I am testing a application which generates 2 XML files. When I try to open those XML files in Notepad++ with XML plugin and click on check syntax I get error "Document labeled UTF-16 but has UTF-8" content.

The developer has developed it taking into account that English and Korean Language support. When I test the application with English font it generates 2 xml files with encoding utf-16. When I generate the XML's with Korean font and text still I am getting error "Document labeled UTF-16 but has UTF-8"

Why does XML syntax checker complain about this.

Thanks,
Anup

Comment: What does it have to do with C#?

Comment: @ S_F, The developer has to re-implement in c# currently its implemented in MFC.

Comment: Please upload a sample file to a binary file-hosting service.